# Custom overlay button and title on youtube video embedding into react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-player

[image: Need to have custom play button like below, and also need to add video title in any position over the video]

[image]

Need to have custom play button like below, and also need to add video title in any position over the video. Currently trying `react-player`. Any help will be appreciated

`import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'`

`<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />`

How to pass custom play button like above image?

[image: Current image]

When ever I pass youtube link, youtube's default overlay is comming, I need customize to it.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing [ask] and then reviewing this question.  You've missed a few key items-- for instance, you have included no code and you have no question in this post.  Without a question, it is difficult to provide an "answer".  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions, updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube does not allow for customizing the play button. To achieve this:

1. Get and place the YouTube video using your existing code
2. Hide the YouTube video
3. Create a `div` that is positioned at the same place as the YouTube video
4. Use a custom image or get the thumbnail image of the YouTube video and use it as the `background-image` of a div
5. Position your custom play-button and custom text in the div
6. When the button is clicked, hide your div, show the YouTube video with autoplay enabled

Answer (score 0):

From the [react-player documentation for "light player mode"](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player#light-player):

> The `light` prop will render a video thumbnail with simple play icon, and only load the full player once a user has interacted with the image. [Noembed](https://noembed.com/) is used to fetch thumbnails for a video URL. Note that automatic thumbnail fetching for Facebook, Wistia, Mixcloud and file URLs are not supported, and ongoing support for other URLs is not guaranteed.
>
> **If you want to pass in your own thumbnail to use, set `light` to the image URL rather than true.**
>
> The styles for the preview image and play icon can be overridden by targeting the CSS classes `react-player__preview`, `react-player__shadow` and `react-player__play-icon`.

*(emphasis added)*

SO-- it appears that to provide a custom preview image you would rewrite your JSX as:

```
<ReactPlayer
    url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U"
    light="path/to/your/preview/image"
/>
```

So you can accomplish this with a custom preview image.  If you need something more dynamic, in which the button has its own hover states, you may need to spin something from scratch or find a different library.